# Excel vba sort by every nth row and delete duplicate

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am having troubles with some excel vba and not even sure if it can be done. I have been looking for a solution for quite some time now.
I have attached images so that it will be easier to understand because it's complicated to write it in code.

So here is a problem:

Image 1 shows default state. 1st, I need to sort sections (bordered cells) by yellow cells. Result is on image2. If I get double positions, I need that row deleted (just row) (image 3)

Some help:
yellow cells are always 4 char cells
Category cell is always F if C cell is 4 char cell
Name cell is always blank if C cell is 4 char cell
Build, draw, position etc will always be in row 8

I managed to get code to select every ''section'' but I am quite sure that this was wrong approach.

Is there any way to do this with excel vba?

Thank you very much,
Best regards,
Mario

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A25000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, "A9").Select
Set ColumnaA = Selection

For Each Cell In ColumnaA

If IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(2, 6).Value) Then
    Cell.Offset(1, 6).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 5).Select
    Set section = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Cell)
End If

If IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value) And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(2, 6).Value) Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 6).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 5).Select
    Set section = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Cell)
End If

Next Cell
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1PW9.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaZoD.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTroT.png)

Comment: Just one of many feasible solutions: Insert a column and concat 4 digit position numbers and the following numbers in that group like 01110,01111,01112,01113,00920,00921,00922,.. Sort that column. Delete the rows with duplicate values in that column. Finally delete the inserted column. You can quickly do this using formulas or via VBA for long term use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @tehscript that building a [composite key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) is the easiest way to do this. So, we're going to:

- build a couple helper columns,
- create composite keys in one of them so we can sort our rows correctly,
- sort the rows,
- delete the duplicates at the bottom, and
- get rid of the helper columns

The composite key is going to be in the form of:

XXXX-SS-LLL

Where "XXXX" is the 4-digit position, "SS" is the "series", or occurrence, of a particular position in a given list (starting at 00, and going up sequentially), and "LLL" is the item number of a given sub-item. So, going from your "image 1", in row 40 we'll have:

0114-01-002

(0114: the position, 01: this is the second 0114 in our list (the first occurred in row 24), 002: the second item underneath this occurrence of 0114)

If you have questions, let me know!

```
Sub sortStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, totalRange As Range, arr() As Variant, lastRow As Long
    Dim index As Long, indexes() As Variant, dict As Object
    Dim position As String, lastPosition As String, compositeKey As String, category As String
    Dim countRowsToDelete As Long

    'our dictionary to manage multiple instances of the same position
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    countRowsToDelete = 0

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    'we add some columns to the right of our data here
    'column 13 will be for a composite key, and 14 will be for marking rows to delete
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 13), ws.Cells(1, 14)).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count + ws.UsedRange.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'grabs the whole range that we're interested in
    Set totalRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, 14))
    'builds a 2-D array of the values of our range
    arr = totalRange.Value2

    lastPosition = ""
    For index = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        position = arr(index, 3)
        category = arr(index, 4)
        'the default for this column is "0", which will mark this row not to be deleted
        arr(index, 14) = 0
        'Checking if this is a "master" row
        If category = "F" Then
            'If it is, check to see if we already have this position somewhere on the sheet
            If dict.Exists(position) Then
                'if we do, increment the "series" of the particular row
                dict(position) = dict(position) + 1
                'if we already have this position, this is a duplicate, so mark it for deletion
                arr(index, 14) = 1
                'increment the number of rows to delete
                countRowsToDelete = countRowsToDelete + 1
            Else
                'we've not come across this position before, so add it to the dictionary
                Call dict.Add(position, 0)
            End If
            'we're building a "composite key" for each row
            compositeKey = position & "-" & Format(CStr(dict(position)), "00") & "-000"
            'this lets us use the "master" position for the subitems in the list
            lastPosition = position
        Else
            'if this is not a "master" row, the 4 character position is going to come from lastPosition
            compositeKey = lastPosition & "-" & Format(CStr(dict(lastPosition)), "00") & "-" & Format(position, "000")
        End If
        'place our composite key in the array
        arr(index, 13) = compositeKey
    Next

    'we've manipulated the array, and are ready to place it back on the spreadsheet
    totalRange.Value2 = arr

    'now that the data is back on the sheet, we can use the in-built excel sort functions
    'here, we sort first by column 14, which will leave the repeats to delete at the bottom
    'we then sort by column 13, which is our composite key
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        Call .SortFields.Add(totalRange.Columns(14), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending)
        Call .SortFields.Add(totalRange.Columns(13), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending)
        .SetRange totalRange.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(totalRange.Rows.count + 1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Dim deleteStartRow As Long
    If countRowsToDelete > 0 Then
        'figure out the start of the rows to be delete for duplicates
        deleteStartRow = lastRow - countRowsToDelete + 1
        'delete the repeat entries
        Call ws.Range(ws.Cells(deleteStartRow, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, 1)).EntireRow.Delete(xlUp)
    End If
    'delete the helper columns
    Call ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 13), ws.Cells(1, 14)).EntireColumn.Delete(xlLeft)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did everything I wanted. Im having some troubles understanding what exactly it did, but ill get to it! Once again thank you!

Comment: @marioweb4net. You're welcome. If you do have questions, please ask. Most of the things in that code are pretty straightforward, but there are a lot of different parts, and putting them all together can be tricky. Anyway, let me know.